# Display Text as submitted

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am writing some text in textarea and showing it using ajax call so when i enter some text and press enter for new line and then enter text then after submitting i cannot get accurate text as i entered
for example in textarea i right this

```
Hi
helo
world
```

then after submit my text a receive it like this

```
Hi helo world
```

how can i get my text as i entered.
this is my textarea code

```
 <p>
     <textarea id="wall_post_comment" name="wall_post_comment></textarea>
 </p>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submit_wall();">Post</a>
```

this is my function

```
function submit_wall()
{
    var text=$('#wall_post_comment').val();
    $.post('<?php echo base_url()?>users/wall_post', { text:text },  
    function(data) {
                $('#wall_post_comment').val('');
                $(data).hide().insertAfter('#wall_post').slideDown('slow');
    }); 
}
```

and this is my model code where i am returning my text

```
function returnWall($text)
{        
    return '<div >

    &nbsp;'.$text.'
   </div>';
}
```

### UPDATE

Comment: Can you please share some code...? Without it, answering your question gets difficult..

Comment: [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your `returnWall()` function is working you can use the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function to convert new line characters to `<br>` or `<br />`

```
function returnWall($text)
{        
   return '<div>&nbsp;'.nl2br($text).'</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just add nl2br into your model code

```
function returnWall($text)
{        
   return '<div >
   &nbsp;'.nl2br($text).'
   </div>';
 }
```